# Apply a custom function on an entire column of data.table?

Tags: r, function, data.table, apply, large-data

I have a very large `Data Table` with two columns. And I wish to apply a custom function on a particular column. The code to generate the problem is as follows:

```
require(data.table)
X <- rep("This is just random text", 1e5)
data <- data.frame(1:1e5, replicate(1, X, simplify=FALSE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(data) <- paste("X", seq_len(ncol(data)), sep="")
DT <- as.data.table(data)
```

Now, we have a large data table which looks like

```
| X1 |            X2           |
|----|-------------------------|
| 1  | This is just random text|
| 2  | This is just random text|
| 3  | This is just random text|
| 4  | This is just random text|
| .. |            ...          |
```

What if I want to do some vector operation on any of this column considering in mind that this data.table will be of very large size (approx `~100M` rows).

Let's take an example of X1 column. Suppose, I want to apply the following function on it:

```
Fun4X1 <- function(x){return(x+x*2)}
```

And a very complex `NLP` function on X2 column which looks something like

```
Fun4X2 <- function(x){
             require(stringr)
             return(str_split(x, " ")[[1]][1])
          }
```

How shall I go about doing this for a large dataset? Please suggest the min. time consuming approach as my `Function` is itself very complex.

P.S. I have tried `foreach`, `sapply`, and of course `for-loop` and all are very slow on a pretty good hardware system.

Comment: What's wrong with using `Fun4X2[DT$X2]` ?

Comment: Also, if you are doing text processing then get familiar with `grep` and `gsub` - the `stringr` functions are simple wrappers around these very powerful functions.

Comment: What about `DT[, list(Fun4X1(X1), Fun4X3(X2))]` where "Fun4X3" is defined as: `Fun4X3 <- function(x) strsplit(x, " ")[[1]][1]`

Comment: @AnandaMahto I am looking for something similar to this but if I use your solution then the output on text column in not vectorized and I get same output even if I have different text in each row

Comment: @Andrie I understand grep and gsub and I am afraid they are not part of my `Function` and as a matter not required. Also the other approach you have mentioned `Fun4X2[DT$X2]` does not give the result. And I am looking for a solution which can run on very large data without causing much problem

Comment: I wasn't paying attention, but just getting rid of your stringr code because I know it is *much* slower. Try this instead: `Fun4X3 <- function(x) vapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(y) y[1], character(1))`. That should also return a vector, not a list.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, also it could be faster with `fixed=TRUE` for this regexp.

Comment: @Arun, true, by several times.

Answer (score 4):

The approach should be no different than applying any other in-built (or package-loaded) function to a specific column in a `data.table`: Use a `list(fun(variable), otherfun(othervariable))` type of construct. You can also name the resulting columns if so desired, otherwise they will be named "V1", "V2" and so on.

In other words, for your problem you can do:

```
DT[, list(X1 = Fun4X1(X1), X2 = Fun4X2(X2))]
```

---

I suspect, however, that a lot of your slowdown might be due to the functions you are actually using. Compare the following slight refinements:

```
Fun4X2.old <- function(x){
  require(stringr)
  return(str_split(x, " ")[[1]][1])
}

Fun4X2.new1 <- function(x) {
  vapply(strsplit(x, " "), 
         function(y) y[1], character(1))
} 

Fun4X2.new2 <- function(x) {
  vapply(strsplit(x, " ", fixed=TRUE), 
         function(y) y[1], character(1))
} 

Fun4X2.sub <- function(x) sub("(.+?) .*", "\\1", x)

X <- rep("This is just random text", 1e5)    

system.time(out1 <- Fun4X2.old(X))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  18.838   0.000  18.659 
system.time(out2 <- Fun4X2.new1(X))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.000   0.000   0.944 
system.time(out3 <- Fun4X2.new2(X))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.584   0.000   0.270 
system.time(out4 <- Fun4X2.sub(X))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.000   0.000   0.222
```

---

One last note, regarding [your comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286717/apply-a-custom-function-on-an-entire-column-of-data-table#comment32077555_21286717):

> @AnandaMahto I am looking for something similar to this but if I use your solution then the output on text column in not vectorized and I get same output even if I have different text in each row

Incidentally, your original `Fun4X2()` (renamed `Fun4X2.old()` above) exhibits the same behavior.

```
DT2 <- data.table(X1 = 1:4, X2 = c("a b c", "d e f", "g h i", "j k l"))
DT2[, list(Fun4X1(X1), Fun4X2.old(X2))]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  3  a
# 2:  6  a
# 3:  9  a
# 4: 12  a

DT2[, list(Fun4X1(X1), Fun4X2.new1(X2))]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  3  a
# 2:  6  d
# 3:  9  g
# 4: 12  j
```

Comment: Thanks @Ananda for the solution. Just 1 quick doubt; can we take this solution and process it in multiple cores simultaneously. What I mean is that if I have 4 cores and 100000 rows, so can I divide the data to say 25k rows for each core and process it and then combine again? As it may boost the speed o almost 4 times. Also, Column 1 can act as a key and Column 2 as a value.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the snowfall package, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/snowfall.pdf,  for parallel computing. You can set up a local cluster and utilize all of your cores. I've found that by using `sfApply` from this package it has reduced most of my computing times by 5X

(I have an 8-core, so it would be 8 times faster, but there is obviously the costs of loading the data into the cluster and collecting it at the end).

e.g.

```
install.packages('snowfall')

require(snowfall)
sfInit( parallel=TRUE, cpus=4 )
sfExport(list=c('DT','Fun4X1','Fun4X2'))
sfApply(DT,1,function(X) return(c(fun4X1(X[1]),fun4X2(X[2]))))
sfStop()
```

With `apply` takes 25.07 sec , with `sfApply` takes 9.11 sec on my machine

Comment: Thanks @James for the efforts. I tried your solution with what @Ananda has given and I am using some functions like as.String from NLP package and more inside the `Fun4X2` so it seems there are some errors like `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 4 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "as.String"`

Comment: Solved the error by calling those packages inside the function itself... Thanks... Will try the new solution on large data and post the feedback and combined method soon...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fast and vectorized function `sub` for the second problem:

```
Fun4X2 <- function(x) sub("(.+?) .*", "\\1", x)

head(Fun4X2(DT[,X2]))
# [1] "This" "This" "This" "This" "This" "This"
```

Comment: That is indeed [the fastest option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21288337/1270695) for this part of the problem, if it is part of the OPs actual issue. +1 for that :-)